# Can't communicate on remote ip using local vip through IPSEC (IPSEC is up + Test port works)

Tags: firewall, ipsec, pfsense, zabbix

good afternoon.
I have the following problem in pfSense:

The Service for package Zabbix Proxy not want to go up.

The scenario is as follows:

1. pfSense has a IPSEC VPN with Zabbix Server

   > Zabbix IP is 192.168.1.248
2. pfSense has a VIP (Virtual IP) linked to pfSense, which is what Zabbix Server will use to communicate on Phase 2 of IPSEC

   > Virtual IP is 172.16.250.10
3. If i go to Diagnostics > Test Port and select interface VIP 172.16.250.10 and try to connect on 192.168.1.248:10052 (Which is the port Zabbix Server is listening)
   i get a SUCCESS message, but if i don't specify a interface, i get a connection error message

When i try to start Zabbix Proxy service, it reports that the Zabbix Server IP is unavailable (Unable to connect to 192.168.1.248:10052...)
So, i believe that the route that Zabbix Proxy is trying to do is NOT through the VIP.

So that's why it's not getting a success message when connecting to the Proxy.
I believe that the Zabbix Proxy service in pfSense is getting a different interface than the VIP one...

I am almost sure that i must have to do some Outbound NAT. I even managed to do one according to the image below, but it's not working.
[image: Outbound NAT Example]

My logic when creating this NAT below (I don't know if I made the rule correctly): Every connection attempt on IP 192.168.1.248 on port 10052, use the VIP interface.

Please, how can i explicity and globally say to pfSense that "All tries on 192.168.1.248:10052 outbound route uses interface VIP address 172.16.250.10" ?

Or if this is not the solution, what can i do ?

Comment: I just googled this problem and went straight to my own question. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by setting a route in System > Routing on pfSense for specific IPs destinations.

This for outbound routes, the other way around I had to create VIPs and use NAT.